# Cordova App Chrome does not set origin file:// on GET

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, webview, cross-domain

We have an ionic app which is using as you know perhpas cordova. If we do a simple XHR GET the webview which is chrome does not add the Origin header `(file://)`, this is a big problem for us.

Is there a way to force XHR or cordova to add always the origin header?
We tried to set the origin header on GETs manually but there is always the usual error for setting origin header as on POST or PUT methods:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) which allow to test on google chrome by enabling cross-origin resource sharing